# Change image in UI depending on the value of the slider

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am trying to make the images change in the UI when the slider's value is changed, right now nothing is happening when i move the slider, this is my code:

```
public class ImagesSlider : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update

public Sprite sprite1;
public Sprite sprite2;
public Sprite sprite3;
public Sprite sprite4;
public Sprite sprite5;
public Sprite sprite6;
public Sprite sprite7;
public Sprite sprite8;
public Sprite sprite9;
public Sprite sprite10;
public Sprite sprite11;

public Slider imageslider;


void Start()
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
}

void Update()
{
    ChangeImage();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void ChangeImage()
{
    if (imageslider.value == 1.0f)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprite1;
    }

    if (imageslider.value == 2.0f)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprite2;
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

If your slider has max value of 1 in it you have to check values between 0-1 since it is float you need to do greater than or less than in your condition.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MySlider : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public Sprite sprite1;
    public Sprite sprite2;
    public Sprite sprite3;
    public Sprite sprite4;
    public Sprite sprite5;
    public Sprite sprite6;
    public Sprite sprite7;
    public Sprite sprite8;
    public Sprite sprite9;
    public Sprite sprite10;
    public Sprite sprite11;

    public Slider imageslider;
    public Image img;


    void Start()
    {
        img = gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ChangeImage();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void ChangeImage()
    {
        if (imageslider.value <= .1f)
        {
            img.sprite = sprite1;
        }

        if (imageslider.value <= .2f && imageslider.value >= .1f)
        {
            img.sprite = sprite2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ive chaged the slider to 11 because theres 11 images, i wanted top have an image per value and when you move up and down it changes the images

Comment: then you have to change the `Slider.maxValue` of the slider to 11 and enable the `Slider.wholeNumbers` to true.

Comment: Note that even with `Slider.wholeNumbers` set to true it is still a `float` so you should rather use [`if(Mathf.Approximately(imageslider.value, 1f)){ ... }`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

Comment: ive changed that slider to 11 and whole number already

Comment: Nothing happens when i try that code @ArtZolinaIII

Comment: @user12719872 make sure this script is attached to the image gameObject and also map the slider to the inspector. what is the error log?